# Jenkins Pipeline, retrieve information from JIRA ticket

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jira

I was just wondering if there was anyway to retrieve information from a Jira ticket and assign it to a variable in Jenkins.

So (just an example) - I'd like to save label from a ticket as $Jira_Label

Answer (score 1):

You can send a REST request to JIRA and retrieve the information, like the label, of a specified issue.

[Here](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/) there is the list of the available requests you can send.